# Button click check a box and display another jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a button:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data1="w1d1" data2="w1d1soup" value="Add Meal to Order"></input>
```

And i have two checkboxes:

```
<input data="w1d1soup" type="checkbox" name="w1d1" id="w1d1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="w1d1soup" value="1">
```

And ive made this jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
            alert("hello");

        var inputValue1 = $(this).attr("data1");
        if ($("#" + inputValue1).is(':checked')) {

            $("#" + inputValue1).attr("checked", false);
            var inputValue2 = $(this).attr("data2");
            $("." + inputValue2).toggle();

        } else {

            $("#" + inputValue1).attr("checked", true);
            var inputValue2 = $(this).attr("data1");
            $("." + inputValue2).toggle();

        }               

        });
```

The idea is, that when you click the button, the first checkbox is marked as "checked" and the second button is toggled to appear.... but i can't seem to get it to work

Any ideas?
(I added alert("hello"); to see if an alert even appears on the button press, and it doesnt)

Comment: At a glance the first thing I notice is that you never close the `function` used for `document.ready`, resulting in a syntax error.  Check your browser's development console for errors.  Consistent indentation will also help you spot structural problems.  It's also a good idea to make this into a runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem so we can observe it.

Comment: You're a legend, i was missing ) and a }.... thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem thanks to davids comment.

```
$(document).ready(
function() {

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {

        var inputValue1 = $(this).attr("data1");

        if ($("#" + inputValue1).is(':checked'))
        {

            $("#" + inputValue1).attr("checked", false);
            var inputValue2 = $(this).attr("data2");
            $("." + inputValue2).toggle();

        }
        else
        {

            $("#" + inputValue1).attr("checked", true);
            var inputValue2 = $(this).attr("data2");
            $("." + inputValue2).toggle();

        }               

    }
    )
}
);
```